# json result undefined

Tags: jquery

i have callback of jquery ajax call with json result as:

```
function (data) {
            alert(data);
            alert(data['169874']);
}
```

and:

```
alert(data) shows: {"169874":"123"}
```

but:

```
alert(data['169874']) shows undefined.
```

why is it undefined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `JSON.parse()` the JSON string before accessing it as Javascript Object:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

This is done automatically by jQuery, if you specify the dataType `json` in a [`$.ajax()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. This is also done implicite by [`$.getJSON()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for instance.